# Which episodes of Detective Conan are canon?

Tags: detective-conan

Which episodes of Detective Conan are canonical to the manga?

After watching the first ~20 episodes, I get the feeling that there are quite a lot of non-canon material so far.

Comment: Conan has hell a lot episodes, but [this is a list of the episodes/movies/OVA/specials (animated or live action) that didn't appear in the Manga.](http://www.detectiveconanworld.com/wiki/Category:Anime_Exclusive) You can see more in [here](http://www.detectiveconanworld.com/wiki/Canon)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305005028/http://members.shaw.ca/makimura/DCN/EPS/DCNCRITEP.html) out. It lists all the essential episodes in the storyline! Here's a copy of the content from that site (as of November 2014) with formatting added:

- 1-5
- 10
- 11
- 18
- 21 (1st appearance of Yoko-chan (idol))
- 27
- 28
- 32
- 34
- 35
- 42
- 43
- 48/49 (absolute must)
- 54
- 57/58
- 68-70
- 76 (enter Kid)
- 77/78
- 81/82 (Minami)
- 96
- 100/101
- 112 (1st appearance of Kobayashi Sumiko (teacher))
- 116-118
- 121/122
- 128
- 129-131
- 132-134 (Kid, 134 only)
- 136/137
- 141/142
- 146/147 (Police Love Story #1)
- 153/154
- 156/157 (Police Love Story #2)
- 162
- 166-168
- 170-171 (Araide intro)
- 174
- 176-178
- 188-193
- 199/200
- 205/206
- 217/218
- 219
- 220-224
- 226/227 (Jodie Santemillion debut)
- 228/229
- 230/231
- 233/234
- 236/237
- 238/239
- 241/241
- 246/247
- 249/250
- 253/254
- 255/256
- 258/259 (Enter James Black)
- 263
- 264-265 (Eri)
- 266-268
- 269
- 271/272
- 277/278
- 279/280
- 284-293
- 297-298 (Eri)
- 299-300
- 301/302
- 304
- 307-311
- 316/317
- 323/324
- 329-330 (Black Organization, Haibara's parents)
- 331/332
- 333/334
- 335/336
- 338/339
- 340/341
- 343/344
- 345 (most critical to date)
- 356
- 358/359
- 361/362
- 381/382
- 385-387
- 390/391
- 394-396
- 398-399
- 400-402
- 406-408
- 418
- 425 (another jaw dropper)
- 426 (Ran)
- 429-430
- 431-432
- 435-436
- 437
- 445
- 446/447
- 449
- 457/458
- 462-465
- 469-470 (Kid)
- 472-473 (Toichi!!)
- 474 (Eri)
- 479 (2hr, Heiji & Hakuba)
- 484-485
- 487 (Police Love Story #8, 1hr special)
- 489 (Eri)
- 490 (Shinichi VS Heiji for the 1st time, but they didn't know it)
- 491-504
- 505-506 (Eri)
- 507-508 (Eisuke knows C is S)
- 509-511 (Enter Okiya or should we say Bourbon?)
- 515 (Kaitou Kid)
- 516-517 (Heiji & Kazuha)
- 521-523 (Shinichi back and he's a killer)
- 528-529 (Eri solves another murder)
- 530-531 (Satou & Takagi)
- 534-535 (Satou & Takagi)
- 537-538 (Kid)
- 542-543 (Okiya helps solve case)
- 545-546 (a bit of Satou's past)
- 554-555 (Heiji & Kazuha)
- 558-561 (Detective Koumei intro)
- 563-564 (Akai (or his twin) lives?)
- 568-569 (Shiratori's love)
- 573-574 (Heiji & Kazuha)
- 579/580/581 (Black Organization, Okiya, "Akai")
- 583-585 (Shiratori/Kobayashi)
- 586-587 (Kid)
- 589-590 (Eri & Kogoro)
- 592-593 (Ran)
- 608-609 (affects all couples)
- 610-613 (Heiji; "Hound of the Baskervilles")
- 616-621 (London case!!)
- 622-623 (Okiya)
- 624 (Shiratori/Chiba)
- 627-628 (Kid)
- 646-647 (Sera intro)
- 648-650 (Sera, Shinichi)
- 651 (1hr SP: Conan VS Heiji)
- 652-655 (Heiji/Kazuha)
- 656-657 (Haibara/Sera/Okiya)
- 659-660 (Chiba/Miike)
- 667-668 (Amuro's 1st appearance)
- 671-674 (Amuro, Sera, Okiya)
- 675-676 (Black Organization hints, relates back to 671-674)
- 681-683 (Takagi/Satou)
- 684-685 (Okiya/Haibara)
- 689 (Eri/Kogoro)
- 690-691 (Okiya/Sera/Y Kudo)
- 699-700 (Haibara/Amuro)
- 701-704 (MYSTERY TRAIN CASE)
- 705-706 (Amuro)
- 710-711 (Heiji/Kazuha/Ohtaki/Heizo)
- 712-715 (Heiji/Kazuha/Ohtaki)
- 722-723 (Tanteidan, Amuro, Okiya)
- 724-725 (Kid, Sera)
- 727-728 (Sera)
- 731-732 (Yumi/Miike/Takagi/Megure)
- 734 (Jodie/Bourbon/Vermouth)
- 740-741 (Sera, Black Organization hints)
- 744-745 (Sera, Makoto)
- 746-747 (Sonoko/Makoto/Kid)
- 748-749 (Takagi/Sato)
- 751-752 (Amuro; Takagi/Sato)
- 754-756 (Sera, Akai, Yamato/Uehara)
- 759-760 (Sera, 1st appearance of her younger sister (?))
- 763-764 (Heiji/Kazuha),
- 770-771 (Amuro//Eri)
- 772-773 (Shinichi/Ran)
- 779-783 (Black Organization/Bourbon/Jodie/Vermouth/Akai)
- 785-786 (Yumi/Haneda)
- 787-788 (Sera/mystery girl)
- 792-793 (mention of Rum, the case itself is not important)

Comment: For me this answer is gold, but is not what the question is asking, since "canonical to the manga" is not "essential [...] in the storyline".
I was looking for your answer though

Answer (score 3):

There is a website called *Animefillerlist*. They list all the canon and filler episodes of certain anime.

[Canon Episodes for Conan](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/detective-conan):

> 1-5, 7-13, 15-16, 18, 20, 22-23, 27-28, 31-32, 34-35, 38-40, 42-43,
>   46, 48-50, 52, 54, 57-58, 60, 63, 68-70, 72, 75-78, 81-82, 84-86, 91,
>   96, 98-105, 110, 113-118, 121-122, 128-134, 136-139, 141-142, 144-147,
>   153-154, 156-157, 162-164, 166-168, 170-174, 176-178, 188-195,
>   199-200, 205-206, 212-213, 217-224, 226-231, 233-234, 238-244,
>   246-247, 249-250, 253-254, 258-259, 263, 266-272, 274-275, 277-280,
>   284-293, 301-302, 304-313, 316-317, 323-327, 329-336, 338-341,
>   343-347, 350-351, 354-356, 358-359, 361-362, 366-367, 371-372,
>   374-375, 381-383, 385-387, 390-391, 394-396, 398-402, 406-408,
>   411-412, 415-417, 421-422, 425, 427-432, 435-436, 438, 443-447, 449,
>   453-455, 457-458, 460, 462-467, 469-470, 472-474, 476-477, 479,
>   481-482, 484-485, 487-488, 490-511, 513-517, 521-526, 528-535,
>   537-538, 542-543, 545-546, 549-552, 557-561, 563-564, 568-569,
>   571-576, 578-581, 583-587, 589-590, 592-593, 597-598, 600-601,
>   608-628, 632-633, 642-657, 659-662, 667-668, 671-676, 681-685,
>   690-691, 699-706, 710-715, 722-725, 727-728, 731-732, 734, 738-741,
>   744-749, 751-752, 754-756, 759-760, 763-766, 770-773, 779-783,
>   785-788, 792-793, 808-812, 814-815, 822-823, 827-828, 830-832,
>   836-837, 843-844, 847-850, 853-854, 861-864, 866-867, 872-874, 878-879